# How to query entries by field values

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype, query, elementquery

I have some entries with a multi-select field called "gallery". We can choose many images to this field.

I have a given image, how can I query entries whose "gallery" contains this given image? Thx!

I have tried like this with no success:

```
Entry::find()
  ->section($section)
  ->galleryImages('contains' . $image->id)
  ->all();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [related to](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) parameter you can use

```
Entry::find()
  ->section($section)
  ->relatedTo(['targetElement' => $image->id, 'field' => 'galleryImages')
  ->all();
```